# Por qué pgAdmin no me deja crear bases de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, pgadmin

Instalé postgreSQL en mi Ubuntu 20.04, luego instalé pdAdmin4 y creé desde la consola un nuevo usuario de postgres con el cual me creo un nuevo servidor. Por default tengo la base de dato llamada postgres e intento crear una nueva base de datos en el mismo servidor pero no me lo permite como se muestra en la imagen siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

1. Ve a la terminal
2. Ejecuta **sudo su postgres**
3. Ejecuta **psql**
4. Luego dale permisos a un usuario para crear base de datos mediante: **ALTER USER *nombreDeUsuario* CREATEDB;**
5. Luego ve al pgAdmin y desconecta el servidor y luego lo conectas, con el usuario al que le diste nuevos permisos

Comment: De esta forma solucioné el problema

Answer (score 0):

No te deja por que estás dando clic derecho en el **Servidor**, tienes que dar clic derecho donde dice **Databases**

[image: Así como en la imagen a continuación]